# When adding aws-java-sdk to the pom, @JsonIgnore doesn't work. Why?

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jackson, aws-sdk

When add `aws-java-sdk` to pom.xml, my existing `@JsonIgnore` annotation doesn't work anymore. But when I delete Amazon SDK (aws-java-sdk) from the pom file, JsonIgnore works well. It is quite weird situation and I don't know the reason.

Jackson version is `1.9.13` and Amazon SDK version is `1.6.12`.

I need to use @JsonIgnore to prevent circular reference on Hibernate models. I also need to use Amazon SDK to work with Amazon S3.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

```
Class Car  {
    private String title;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Model model;
    …
}

Class Model  {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="manufacturer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Manufacturer manufacturer;
    …
}

Class Manufacturer {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "manufacturer")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Model> models;
    …
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by the "annotation doesn't work anymore"? Do you mean it doesn't compile? Is the aws-java-sdk pulling in other dependencies that affects your classpath? Try running `mvn dependency:tree`

Comment: @matt **/api/cars** returns cars list. With JsonIgnore annotation there is no circular reference (because of car -> model -> manufacturer->model). After adding Amazon AWS library to the pom file, circular reference error occurs. There is no compilation error. 
Btw, I've resolved the problem by changing `org.codehaus.jackson` to `com.fasterxml.jackson.core`. Now `jackson-core` version is 2.3.0. I just wondered what was going on.

Comment: sounds like aws-java-sdk was loading version 2.3.0 of the Jackson library - which has a package change to all of their classes - and you were using 1.9.0. Might be a good idea to make sure that your API is configured to use exactly the Jackson ObjectMapper and version you want it to, rather than just finding whatever is on the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matt B is right... The AWS SDK has a dependency on `jackson-annotations`, `jackson-databind`, and `jackson-core`.  The use of `@JsonIgnore` changed after Jackson v1.9: http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnore.html